# Is there an IRB equivalent of .bash_profile/.bash_rc/.profile?

Tags: ruby, command-line, irb, bash

Is there a configuration file that is loaded every time an IRB session is started?

For example I'd like to be able to require certain libraries and enable them for every session in IRB.

Answer (score 3):

The file is called `~/.irbrc`. [Here](https://github.com/logankoester/irbrc/blob/master/irbrc) is an example of one (found while googling "irbrc").